# JavaScript--how to pass scope to reader.onload method

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using the ExtJS Framework.

Inside my reader.onload fn I make an Ajax request and in the success function I call a different function using "this", but "this" is undefined.

```
reader.onload = function(e){
  //do stuff

  Ext.Ajax.request({
    url:url,
    params:params,
    method:"POST",
    scope:this,
    success:function(resp){
      //decode resp;
      console.log(this);//FileReader obj, not the controller obj this code is in
      if(resp.something){
        this.foo(resp); //this.foo isundefined
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Elsewhere on SO in another post someone answered passing scope like so:

```
reader.onload = (function(e){
  //do stuff
}(this));
```

but when I do that "e" becomes undefined.

Comment: So you want to reference `reader` from inside of `success`?

Comment: no I want "this" to refer to the controller class in which all of this code is in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep a reference to the desired object using something like `self`.

```
var self = this;
reader.onload = function(e) {
  ...
  Ext.Ajax.request({
    url:url,
    params:params,
    method:"POST",
    scope:self,
    success:function(resp){
      if(resp.something){
        this.foo(resp);
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: ah, yes. Forgot about that. I've used it elsewhere before. But was more curious about how to pass scope param.

Comment: @stackato What version of ExtJS are you using?

Comment: cool, thatll work too. But I was just curious why I am unable to pass scope param along with "e" to the onload method.

Comment: Because `onload` is called at another time, not when you first declare it. I suppose you could use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), then you could just set `scope: this`. (bind example: `reader.onload = function(e) { ... }.bind(this);`)